# triggering a dblclick event in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to trigger a double click event on an element in angular.

```
        $timeout(function () {
                var elem = document.getElementById(id);
                angular.element(elem).trigger("dblclick")
        }, 1);
```

the element that has the event listener:

```
        var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("id", function (d) {
            if (d.id)
              return d.id;
            else
              return Math.random();
        })
        .on("dblclick", function () {
            console.log("dblclick");
        });
```

Nothing happens. What am I doing wrong here?

BTW, it enters the function that invokes the trigger.
The trigger doesn't invoke the dblclick.

Comment: works fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/eNOZVJoVGZmtiXiPWq9v?p=preview  is your scenario different?

Comment: It is not exactly the same because I add the event listener programmatically. I'm not saying it won't work, though...

Answer (score 0):

You have to `wrap` lines in `$timeout` function.

```
$timeout(function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    angular.element(elem).triggerHandler("dblclick");
},0);
```

The `$timeout()` process is the regular Javascript `setTimeout` function
 which by default, at the end of it, triggers `$apply()`. You can also 
 instruct `$timeout()` not to invoke the `$apply()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to fire a double click element just do the following.

```
<h1 ng-dblclick="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">Welcome</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the ".on" method in my code is of the d3 library, that uses a different naming convention for events *"__ontype"*.

See this link:

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#on

This convention does not correspond with the jquery or angular's jqlite "trigger()" or "triggerHandler()".

Using native javascript solved the problem:

```
        var elem = document.getElementById(id);
        var event = new MouseEvent("dblclick");
        elem.dispatchEvent(event);
```

**In addition**, in d3 version 4 there is a designated api for dispatching an event:

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch